# How to lock HTML element in fixed position after initial display?

Tags: jquery, html, css-position

I'm building a photo web site and have a small problem with my slideshow that relies heavily on JQuery. There's a very small time period in between the transition between slides where my menu on the far right (see photo below) shifts to the left next to the tiled pictures because the main photo in the middle gets its display set to "none" as part of the transitioning sequence. It's so quick, the menu effectively blinks on the left and reappears where it should be once the next slide is displayed in the center panel. Is there a way I can determine the absolute position of the right side menu once the page is initially displayed, then use JQuery in the document.ready method to set the location of the menu permanently so that it doesn't shift when the main photo disappears for that brief time?

[image]

Comment: Care to create and share a jsfiddle for the problem you are facing. We'll be able to help you in a much better way. Just looking at the image doesn't give much idea about the issue.

Comment: seems to me you should be able to set it in your css and let the middle image panel be responsive. A demo would help

Answer (score 0):

You already know the position from the right side. It is zero plus whatever margin you have set.  So just set the CSS properties to position:absolute;right:0 and it will not nee to  change position.